# Get route by name in different namespace

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

Structury of folders:

```
-App
  -CustomClasses
    Menu.php
  -Http
    -Controllers
      TestController.php
```

When i use `Route::getRoutes()` from my `TestController.php` i've got all routes, but when i use same method in `Menu.php` result is empty. Therefore `route('route-name')` which i need also doesn't work correctly. I think it might be because of different namespaces, but is there any simple way to get route url by route name in `Menu.php` or any other file outside Controllers folder?

Comment: I think you are missing something here, routes are defined in the separate route file (web.php etc) not in Controller.

Comment: Yes they are. But i just want to get their url by their names.

Comment: What do you get if you dump the route in question from each file?
`route('route-name')` in your TestController and Menu classes?

Comment: You need to be in the same namespace where routes file is defined or define routes file in your own namespace

Comment: when and where are you making references to this `Menu.php` file?

Answer (score 0):

After some time i found solution myself. In `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` there are two methods: `register()` and `boot()`. I created instance of Menu object in `boot()` method, but still received empty route list. I notticed that in `config/app.php` there is a list of service providers, but order is important here.

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
// App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
```

As you can see `AppSeriveProvider` is before `RouteServiceProvider` which means Route's boot method is run last, so there are no routes yet if i try to get them in Menu object which is creater in `AppServiceProvider`.

My solution is to create `MenuServiceProvider` and load it after Route's provider instead create it in `AppServiceProvider`.